# HTTP Request via SOCKS5 using Linux C

Tags: c, linux, http

I am trying to do HTTP Request using SOCKS5 Proxy in C language, i tried the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    struct addrinfo hints, *res;
    int sockfd;
    memset(&hints,0,sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    getaddrinfo("localhost","9050",&hints,&res);

    sockfd = socket(res->ai_family,res->ai_socktype,res->ai_protocol);
    int connected = connect(sockfd,res->ai_addr,res->ai_addrlen);
    if (connected == -1) {
        perror("Error");
    }
    char buffer[256];
    char msginit[256];
    msginit[0] = '\5'; //Protocol number
    msginit[1] = '\2'; //# of authentication methods
    msginit[2] = '\0'; //no authentication 
    msginit[3] = '\2'; //user+pass auth

    //get dest
    memset(&hints,0,sizeof hints);
    memset(res,0,sizeof *res);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    getaddrinfo("duckduckgo.com","80",&hints,&res);
    struct sockaddr_in *ip = (struct sockaddr_in *)res->ai_addr;
    uint32_t* addr=&(ip->sin_addr.s_addr);

    //copy dest to request
    memcpy (msginit+4,addr,sizeof (uint32_t)); 

    send(sockfd, (void *)msginit, (size_t)strlen(msginit),0);
    printf("Sent.\n");
    recv(sockfd,buffer,256,0); //This is where it gets stuck!
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
}
```

it says it send but request isn't send to site and i also cannot read any data from recv, any idea how i could fix that?

Comment: `strlen(msginit)` is wrong. C strings are zero terminated, so it'll stop at `msginit[2] = '\0'`. You'll need something else to track how much data you have in your buffers. Even if you're now negotiating the connection correctly, you're not sending any HTTP request down it.

Comment: can you please tell me how to edit this code to send HTTP request using SOCKS5? thank you.

Comment: I don't know enough about socks5. It would be easier to just use curl or libcurl which has built-in support for socks5 I think.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you can't use strlen() to get the used amount of a binary buffer. In this case you know that you want to send 4 bytes plus `sizeof (uint32_t)`, so you can use this in your send call, and you will no longer be stuck. Otherwise, you will only send the two first bytes (the bytes before \0), and the proxy will wait for more data before responding.

(For more help with SOCKS5, there is plenty of available information elsewhere. But the above solves the specific problem with your code as posted.)